# Manipulating JQuery .text() output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, methods

I am building a Twitter like site that is fed random tweets that I want to export to the website in a particular manner. I have most of my requirements met up to this point, the only issue I am having is turning the jQuery text of a Twitter user and handle it into a link that can be clicked.

My code snippet below exhibits my work so far:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $body = $('.middle');
    $body.html();
    var index = streams.home.length - 1;
    var newTweets = function(index){
        while(index >= 0){
            var tweet = streams.home[index];
            var $tweet = $('<div class=tweetBox></div>');
            $tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message + tweet.created_at);
            $tweet.appendTo($body);
            index -= 1;
        }  
    }
    newTweets(index);
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        index = streams.home.length - 1;
        newTweets(index); 
    });
});
</script>
```

The line that is giving the issue is `$tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message + tweet.created_at);`
I want to take tweet.user and convert it into a click-able link. Any suggestions on ways to attack this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: So `$tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message + tweet.created_at);` is giving you what you expect, but you just want to make it clickable?

Comment: Then replace this `$tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message + tweet.created_at);` with `var $link = $('<a />', {
    href: '#',
    text: '@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message + tweet.created_at
});

$tweet.append($link);`

Comment: That turns the entire tweet into a link instead of just the handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the  `HTML` function of jQuery.  http://api.jquery.com/html/

like this:

```
var link = $('<a>', {text: tweet.user, href: '#'}).prop('outerHTML');
$tweet.html('@' + link + ': ' + tweet.message + tweet.created_at);
```

it will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then this is what you want

```
var link = $('<a>', {text: tweet.user, href: '#'}).prop('outerHTML');
$tweet.html('@' + link + ': ' + tweet.message + tweet.created_at);
```

Comment: I like the idea that you have here but it is just giving me literally what I type in. The username no longer appears.

Comment: this is what is seen now `@<a href="#">douglascalhoun</a>: that wizard made my money #yoloSun Jan 03 2016 06:20:18 GMT-0500 (EST)`